# Extracting images and text from an mht file

Tags: mhtml

I have a mht file that contains images and some text. When I open it with notepad++, I see xml and then illegible text which I think are images.
Can somebody tell me how can I extract images and text from an mht file using a java program?
Thanks.

Comment: look at the file format, write a decoder based on that, profit! The content of an MHTML file is encoded as if it were an HTML e-mail message, using the MIME type multipart/related. The first part of the file is normally encoded HTML; subsequent parts are additional resources identified by their original URLs and encoded in base64. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML so basically if you know how to work with that sort of encoding in email you should be able to apply the same to these files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting Content from MHT Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268486/extracting-content-from-mht-document)

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit old, but Open it in Internet Explorer, and save as HTML also do the job

Update:

If you open the .mht file in IE, then save it, with the "Save as type" set to "Webpage, complete (*.htm;*.html)", then it will create the '*filename*.htm' file, as well as a '*filename*_files' directory. In that directory will be a lot of .tmp files. For output from the MS "Problem Steps Recorder", these will include among them a bunch of files with '(1)' in the name (as in there might be a '*mhtD3B8.tmp*' file as well as a '*mhtD3B8(1).tmp*' file). The '(1)' files are the images, in .jpg format, simply with a .tmp extension. Search for all the files with '(1)' in the name from that folder, and copy them to a different directory.

Once in the new directory, open a cmd window pointed there. To change all the extensions at once, type "*rename *.tmp *.jpg*" (without the quotes) and press Enter. Voila - all the image files are extracted.

As for accessing the text - since the file is now saved as a .htm file, you should be able to open that file in Notepad++ and parse/read it properly there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am finding that all the files without the `1` in their name, eg `mhtD3B8.tmp`, are 0kb, when i open them in code editor, there is no contents.

Answer (score 4):

There's an open-source `perl` tool called [`unmht`](http://www.volkerschatz.com/unix/uware/unmht.html) which should do the job:

> The first HTML file in the archive is taken to be the primary web
>   page, the other contained files for "page requisites" such as images
>   or frames. The primary web page is written to the output directory
>   (the current directory by default), the requisites to a subdirectory
>   named after the primary HTML file name without extension, with
>   "_files" appended. Link URLs in all HTML files referring to requisites
>   are rewritten to point to the saved files.

Comment: Didn't work. Got error: "Can't find Content-Type header - not a MIME HTML file?"

Comment: @XP1 That makes sense as the "Content-Type" headers are integral for [this format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) to work.

Answer (score 0):

All this doesn't seem to work anymore nowadays, at least for Chrome saved mhtml's, and it's not even in Java. Nevertheless a quick and dirty way on Windows was typing into WSL

```
sudo apt install mpack
```

then

```
munpack filename.mhtml
```

then append jpg extension to all generated files so Windows Explorer gives you a preview to see which files are images.

PS: Since munpack outputs the MIME-Types of each file line by line to `stdout` one could write a script that appends the correct file extensions after the munpack-process.

Comment: It doesn't retain the original filenames. Too much hassle to rename manually. Use [mht2htm](https://pgm.bpalanka.com/mht2htm.html), which retains the filenames of the extracted files.

Answer (score 0):

**mht2htm** worked for me. It retains the filenames of the extracted files.

> mht2htm converts MS Internet Explorer .mht files into common .html
> files you can open on any system with any browser.
>
> mht2htm will extract all files from mht file in single directory. Then
> it will try to find addresses to extracted files and replace them with
> relative address. Other addresses to remote files will not be changed
> so you can get them from internet (if you wish).

Official website:

- https://pgm.bpalanka.com/mht2htm.html

Download:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/mht2htm/