# How do I host an mhtml file on a webserver?

Tags: html, server, webserver, mhtml

I want to just be able to get people to go a link to an mhtml file hosted on a server and be able to see the fully formatted webpage that you'll see when you save the file and open it in Google Chrome (Apparently IE works as well, Firefox and Microsoft Edge do not work). How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Browsers don't display mhtml files, since they are basically archives holding the contents of a web page (i.e. exactly what happens when you try to save a page in Google Chrome). If you want your file to be viewed normally, you should [extract the files from the mhtml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476678/extracting-images-and-text-from-an-mht-file) and then host them separately.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might as well post this as an answer for whomever else gets this problem.

Upon renaming the mhtml file to an mht file, and [Extractmht](https://www.legroom.net/software/extractmht) can be used to convert the file to an html file, which can then be hosted.

[2022 Edit]:
Alternatively, open the mhtml file in Chrome/Firefox and use an extension like [Singlefile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle) to download it as a proper html page.